# how do i update a nested array to add a unique ObjectId to each element?

Tags: mongodb

i have tried 2 methods and both did not work

```
db.exams.updateMany({},{$set: {"exams.$[].questions.$[].id" : new ObjectId()  }  })
```

and

```
db.exams.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$exams"},
    {$unwind:"$exams.questions"},
    {$unwind:"$exams.questions.question"},
    {$set:{"exams.questions.id" : new ObjectId() }}
])
```

I keep getting the same ObjectId for all elements , but i want it to generate a new objectId for each one

Comment: You can use the mongo db aggregate methods $map https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/

Comment: but @adam.k that is in the project stage i want to update the elements not return an array , and i tried it and even on projection it still returns the same ObjectId ```
db.exams.aggregate([
    {$project : {
        newId :{$map:{
            input : "$exams.questions",
            in: {"id": new ObjectId()}
        }}
    } }
])```

Comment: add sample documents

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. I haven't tested it...

```
db.exams.aggregate([
  {$map: {$input: "exams.questions.id", as: "id" in: new ObjectId()} },
  {$out: "your collection"}
  ])
```

Comment: $map is not a pipeline stage so you must use it only with $project i think , and i have already tried it ``` db.exams.aggregate([ {$project : { newId :{$map:{ input : "$exams.questions", in: {"id": new ObjectId()} }} } } ])``` and it did not work still same objectId for all elements

Answer (score 0):

Hey in this case you can try to use the mongodb push operator.

```js
db.exams.find({}).forEach((item) => {                           // here im getting the array and using a foreach im calling the mongodb update function only thing is you will have to pass an id for to select the doc needed to be updated.
      db.exams.update({'array.userid': item.userid}, {
        $push: {
          'array.$.uniqeId': new ObjectId()
        }
})
```

Its not the best code I've written but this is what I have used to do a similar thing.
You can check the [mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#example-push-each) docs here